# When trying to install .Net Framework install wont succeed bc "The Function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction."

Tags: .net

What does this mean and how can I resolve the issue? I'm trying to install Quickbooks but cant bc its saying that .net framework 7 is required. But during the installation process after downloading .net framework 7, this is the message I'm receiving. I currently have windows 8 on the computer I'm using btw

Comment: Impressive, since there's been no version of .NET Framework labelled with a version number of 7. What did it *actually* say? And what have you *attempted* to install?

Comment: I'm sorry, 4.7 not 7! I attempted to download 4.7 and 4.8 but both have said the same thing..."The function attempted to use a name that is reserved for use by another transaction."